# Python project with multiple entry points and one config file

Tags: python, configuration-files

I have a project that has multiple stages, each one with a main.py and multiple entry points and all of them use the same config file.
For example,

```
App/
  Stage1/
     main.py
     step1.py
     step2.py
     utils/
       __init_.py
       util1.py
       util2.py
  Stage2/
    same structure as Stage1/
  configparser.py
  config.ini
  README.md
```

The mains import the steps and the utils package in they directory. However, I want all the steps to also be entry points so I can test them sometimes, they do not import eachother, only utils package. I run Stage1 in different frequency of Stage2, so I would not want to have a BigStage.py in root.
All mains and steps use the same config file and configparser.py.

However, in python I cannot import a toplevel file, I can do this by using a virtualenv or adding it to PYTHONPATH or using sys.path. Today I am using sys.path.insert(1, 'App/'), but this is a dirty solution.
What would be the best practice?.

Comment: Use standard Python packaging. See https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/. The basics are having a `setup.py` file and a call to `setuptools`. The rest is project dependent and depends on your specific goals

Comment: If your codebase is under frequent enough development that re-packaging is inconvenient, you could also just work on letting go of the guilt & shame associated with changing PYTHONPATH :^) I used to feel like you, and then I worked on a huge, fast-moving python project that it would be incredibly annoying to repackage constantly, and my coworkers convinced me it was ok to change PYTHONPATH, and it felt really good. You almost definitely already do a bunch of environment-altering by using a virtualenv, right? it's just one extra line to whatever your environment-activating script is.

Comment: @SaraSinback the better way to do that is to use `python setup.py develop`. It sym links into site-packages so you don't have to constantly repackage while developing. Using `PYTHONPATH` will work, but there's issues w/ reproducibility (I don't know what your `PYTHONPATH` is set to, you don't know what mine is set to, etc). Standard packaging avoids the "what is your `PYTHONPATH` set to" game entirely

Comment: @MattMessersmith Thanks for the advice - that's definitely cool, I didn't know about that feature, and I bet other people could benefit from that advice as well :)